# How can I print a square consisting of numbers from 1 to 9 (from the example) using a 1 line code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, printing, list-comprehension

I need to write a code in 1 line, which will print this:

```
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
6789012345
7890123456
8901234567
9012345678
```

I did this:

```
print([print(i) for i in range(10)])
```

but this code is completely wrong, the output is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I think I should use `map()` and `lambda` but I have no idea how can i do it, I am just learning...

Comment: Do you know what a lambda is? I can assure you it's not as scary as a wolf. Example: `lambda x: x**2` is but a function that takes x as an input and returns the square of it.

Comment: What I want you to do is write a function that takes n as an input and returns 0123456789 if n is 0, 1234567890 if n is 1 and so on.

Comment: BTW: No if statement. Hint: Use the modulus operator %

Comment: okay, i'll try, so should i put lambda in a map()?

Comment: I know a solution was provided. Yet, I want you to learn. You first write a function that creates a single line of 0 to 9 or 1, 2...0. That's a building block for the final solution. What TomRon is doing is exactly that.

Comment: Yes, i have almost got it, in my case I can't use ```\n```, so unfortunately, I can't accept TomRon's solution, but using lambda and % will help, i think

Comment: Well, you can avoid the \n by calling print within map. Kind of a hack though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print("\n".join([("".join(str((i+j)%10) for i in range(10))) for j in range(10)]))
```

Note that the print function returns `None` that's the reason you have `None` printed so many times and you need nested loops to print this 2D array.

Comment: how can i do it without "\n"?

Comment: The `\n` creates a new line, I don't have an idea how to do it without it on a one-linear

Comment: i found an alternative
```chr(10)``` instead of ```\n```